# Pgloader can't connect to PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, pgloader

I'm trying to transfer a MySQL database to a PostgreSQL database using `pgloader`.
I'm using Windows 11, `PostgreSQL 16` and `pgloader 3.6.3`.
Both databases are on my computer and `pgloader` is installed in `WSL` (Ubuntu).
When I try to run this command:

```
pgloader mysql://root@localhost:3306/mysqlDB pgsql://postgres:myPassword@localhost:5432/postgresDB
```

I get this error message from pgloader:

```
KABOOM!
FATAL error: Failed to connect to pgsql at "localhost" (port 5432) as user "postgres": Database error 28P01: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   Failed to connect to pgsql at "localhost" (port 5432) as user "postgres": Database error 28P01: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
What I am doing here?
Failed to connect to pgsql at "localhost" (port 5432) as user "postgres": Database error 28P01: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I'm sure the password for `postgres` is correct because it is the same password I use to access the database from `pgadmin 4`.

I tried to change the authentication method in `pg_hba.conf` to "trust" but that hasn't worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If changing it to trust "didn't work" with the same error message, then you didn't actually change it.  You edited the wrong file, or the wrong line, or didn't reload the config, or something like that.

Comment: Look in the db server's log file to find the complete message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I was using localhost when I should have used the IP address of my computer.